# Click function 'jQuery' for dynamic list items (using Knockout.js) not work

Tags: jquery, function, knockout.js, click, document-ready

I have the following HTML (using knockoutjs).

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: contacts">
   <li class="user-box"><span class="user-box-name" data-bind="text: username"></span></li>
</ul>
```

When he tried to assign the event 'click' to the class via jQuery ("user-box-name"), I can not. This way:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.user-box-name').on('click',function(){
        callFunction();
      })
      function callFunction(){
      }
    });
```

And it did not work! Has anyone experienced this? Is it because the object is dynamic? I am a beginner with knockoutjs.

The function you want to call this inside document.ready!

Already very grateful for the time of you.

Comment: DId you really mean `$(.user-box-name)`instead of `$(".user-box-name")` ?

Comment: Yes there are even quotes, writing error. FIXED!

Comment: @lgao are these li's added dynamically?

Comment: YEAH ARE MAN..! with foreach

Comment: @lgao that is not dynamic, however did you check the documentation? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Comment: Yes! I tried that! But I need a variable that is inside document.ready. And the method I'm trying to call this also inside document.ready :(- Thanks for your time!

Comment: @lgao try this `$(document).on('click','.user-box-name', function(){`

Comment: Yes it works! Even had already done it! I wonder if it has the anchor via knockoutjs like our friend here mentioned below! But this function inside document.ready ... - Thank you for your time

Comment: yes friend is dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using knockout, you may use it's special binding "click".
Like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: contacts">
    <li class="user-box"><span class="user-box-name" data-bind="text: username, click: function() { alert(':)') }"></span>  </li>
</ul>
```

Knockout allows you to use all the advantages of MVVM approach.
So it's even better to define handlers in your view model, neither attach handlers with jQuery.

Comment: Yes! I tried that! But I need a variable that is inside document.ready. And the method I'm trying to call this also inside document.ready :(- Thanks for your time! –

Comment: In this case you can use binding like "click: $root.funcFromDocReady". And add this func to VM. Sure you should call applyBindings on document.ready too.

Comment: Thanks dude, you could give me an example? - Thanks for your time!

Comment: argument to the click handler is the data context for the row http://jsfiddle.net/AqJzC/1/